# Liquibase dont work

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I have the follow problem on my system.
I have a table on h2 database with field type date, but when i try insert data on liquibase script its return an error said unxpected error beacuse not have java.util.Date

this is error on my console

[image: Error on console]

create table

```
#tabela Aluno
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: Nicholas
      changes: 
        - createTable:
            tableName: Aluno
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: AluId
                  type: int
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: AluNome
                  type: varchar(50)
              - column:
                  name: AluEnd
                  type: varchar(50)
              - column:
                  name: AluCPF
                  type: varchar(11)
              - column:
                  name: AluBairro
                  type: varchar(50)
              - column:
                  name: AluCel
                  type: varchar(11)
              - column:
                  name: AluTel
                  type: varchar(10)
              - column:
                  name: AluPaga
                  type: varchar(30)
              - column:
                  name: AluDataEnt
                  type: date
              - column:
                  name: AluDataVenc
                  type: date
```

Insert data on tale

```
#popular Aluno
  - changeSet:
      id: 88801
      author: Nicholas
      changes:
        - insert:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: AluId
                  type: int
                  value: 1
              - column:
                  name: AluNome
                  type: varchar(50)
                  value: Mariana Celegati
              - column:
                  name: AluEnd
                  type: varchar(50)
                  value: Rua Siqueira Bueno, 90
              - column:
                  name: AluCPF
                  type: varchar(11)
                  value: 44455522211
              - column:
                  name: AluBairro
                  type: varchar(50)
                  value: Mooca
              - column:
                  name: AluCel
                  type: varchar(10)
                  value: 55552222
              - column:
                  name: AluTel
                  type: varchar(11)
                  value: 966662222
              - column:
                  name: AluDataEnt
                  type: date
                  valueDate: 2017-02-15
              - column:
                  name: AluDataVenc
                  type: date
                  valueDate: 2018-02-15
            tableName: Aluno
```

here is my dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using java 1.8

Comment: The `DATE` type in H2 (and SQL standard) is for date-only values without time-of-day and without time zone. The `java.util.Date` type is a date-plus-time in UTC value. Square peg, round hole. Use `java.time.LocalDate` class instead. Never use the legacy date-time Java classes outside the *java.time* package, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an error said unexpected error because not have java.util.Date

It actually said that it doesn't expect java.util.Date type.

I'm not sure, but it looks like the issue in Liquibase itself: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3108 As there is no fix for that at this time, I'd try to rollback to some old versions and test whether they have this error or they aren't.

Comment: i use code like it on another project and it run normal

Comment: So then you have a change to properly debug it :)

Comment: I think this is a java bug or similar, but i will try debug

Comment: Your sugestion is do a downgrade on liquibase version right ?